# implementing interface from other assembly can be protected?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I m implementing interface which is in other assembly as projected. I have added assembly reference and name space but cannot access it ?  I want to implement it in my class and of course interface and class are in different assemblies.   I m getting compile time error "cant access due to protection level.."

to me it looks weried. Can't I access this `interface` without making it `public` ?

Code:

```
namespace DAL
{
   interface IStdService
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If an interface is `protected`, it must be nested within another class. `protected` within that class means that access is only granted within that class, or within any subclass of that class. Are you deriving from the class that the interface in question is nested in?

Comment: The interface you are showing, though, is *not* `protected` ...

Comment: Is the interface `protected` or `internal`? If you need to implement it in other assemblies, maybe `public` is good for you.

Comment: The interface you are showing still isn't `protected`, as expressed by your question title. [The default accessibility for interfaces is `internal`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

Comment: Show us the actual structure of what you've got - sufficient so we can reproduce your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have anything in a namespace marked `protected`. Only `internal` and `public` are possible.

It is only possible to do these since the others won't make sense. As O.R. Mapper already said, this only makes sense if they are part of an class already.

If you write this code:

```
protected interface IInterface
{
}
```

It gives the error at compile time:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal

This does compile:

```
internal interface IInterface
{
}
```

and it will make the interface available only inside the assembly, *unless* you make it available through the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

The code in your latest sample:

```
interface IInterface
{
}
```

marks the interface `internal` which is the default for classes, interfaces, etc, but with interfaces this means they are only available inside the assembly, as explained before.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It's more like ... it wilfully ignores and redefines parts of the question.

Comment: The question does not clarify whether the interface *is* immediately within a namespace, or whether it is nested within another class, in which case the access modifier `protected` is perfectly possibly.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I hope the answer is more clear now.

Comment: The OP shows an interface directly in a namespace, so it probably `internal`, not `protected`. `InternalsVisibleTo` is a good addition because it attempts to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, now I had to downvote this. This "answer" is a random bunch of assumptions and guesswork into various directions. I am not saying that is originally your fault, because the question *is* ambiguous, but as it stands, that just means the question cannot yet be answered and must be clarified. Future readers will not be helped by an unclear question and an answer that answers something differently because of more or less random guessing what was actually meant in this particular case.

Comment: @Kobi: Until just a moment ago, the OP also showed the `public` access modifier rather than what was described in the text. I wouldn't trust in the accuracy of that code snippet yet.

Comment: But if the question is clear enough, and the code sample supports that, why is answering it a problem?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Actually, it was `pulic`. I didn't trust that either...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Kobi: I thought of that being a typo.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - It was a typo, but it also shows the OP isn't posting their real code, which is usually useless.

Comment: @Kobi: You are right. So the assumption was wrong. My bad.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Maybe we have different approaches at responding to questions. I tend to wait for as long as possible (until the question has been sufficiently refined to be well-written with respect to the particular problem at hand) before I answer and thereby "conclude the thread". In my opinion, that has the beneficial effects that the OP automatically gets used to writing better questions in the first place, and in turn, the whole resulting question + answer combo will be more easily readable and thus more useful to future visitors. Till then, comments are much more appropriate.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Thanks for your reply. I want it to be clear too, but I often see typo's in code samples where the actual question was clear and didn't need code to support that. I tend to answer them in the good faith the OP did write the code sample by hand.